# d3d9: creating a cube texture from 6 images

Tags: c++, directx-9

I was wondering how I'd go about creating a cube texture from 6 png images in directx 9 (c++). I've found similar questions in directx 11, but was wondering how I'd go about this here.

Comment: First of all, why are you using legacy DirectX 9 in the first place? You should be using DirectX 11. Direct3D 9 debug device / developer runtime is not available on modern versions of Windows OS anyhow.

Comment: Second, you can use legacy D3DX9 to load cubemaps from ``DDS`` files, so you can use DirectX 11 era tools for creating cubemap ``DDS`` files and it will likely work as long as you stick with legacy formats. See [texassemble](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texassemble) and [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/02/05/the-dds-file-format-lives/). You can also use the legacy DirectX SDK--which you are forced to use with Direct3D 9 anyhow--and use the ``DXTex.exe`` tool to build the cubemap ``DDS``.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for the replies - I'm having to use directx 9 due to some company requirements. I've thought of the dds conversion but then I'd prefer not to tell artists that they need to apply a conversion tool, hence was hoping that I could somehow get this done internally through code.

Comment: I'd revisit the requirements. You can support older DirectX 9 era video cards using DirectX 11 API. See [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro). The only reason to use legacy Direct3D 9 ever anymore is to support Windows XP.

Comment: You can use the legacy D3DX9 function ``D3DXLoadSurfaceFromSurface`` to load each face of a cubemap you obtain from ``IDirect3DCubeTexture9::GetCubeMapSurface`` copying from a loaded 2D texture obtained from ``IDirect3DTexture9::GetSurfaceLevel``. You can the use ``D3DXFilterTexture `` to generate the mipmaps. I don't have any handy sample code of doing this, but it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn That blog post was so informative! I'm going to have a better look and have a crack at persuading management. Thanks for the function references as well!